# static route w/ next hop to VPN gets "Network is unreachable'

Tags: linux, networking, vpn

Ubuntu 14.04, linux kernel 3.13.0-77-generic

I have 3 servers A, B, and C. Servers A and B are in the same network (Rackspace) and server C is in another Network (AWS). I have a VPN connection that goes from server B to the VPC that server C is located in. The VPN connection works, I can send traffic across it from server B to server C and vice versa. What I have not been able to figure out is how to route traffic from server A to server C. I believe the solution is to add a static route on server A, like so:

```
$> route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.252.0.0 gw xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the private ip address of server B. However, the output of this command is

```
SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable
```

I can ping and route traffic to server B from server A, so I assume the unreachable network is the one that is across the VPN tunnel.

```
#/ect/sysctl.conf on server B
-----------------------------
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 1

net.ipv4.conf.eth0.arp_notify = 1
vm.swappiness = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 87380 33554432
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 65536 33554432
net.core.rmem_max = 33554432
net.core.wmem_max = 33554432
net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects = 0
net.ipv4.icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses = 1
```

Not sure if I'm using the `route` command incorrectly, or if this is even the right way to route traffic from server A through the vpn to server C.

I have also tried specifying a single host -- the private ip of server C (instead of the CIDR of the whole VPC) -- in the `route add` command but I get the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Servers A and B must be in a link local range. Check addresses and masks.
Tray use **ip route**, like:
    ip route add 10.0.0.0/14 via xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Comment: That also returns "Network is unreachable". When I run `traceroute x.x.x.x` from server A there is a gateway before x.x.x.x (let's call it y.y.y.y), and I am able to run `ip route add 10.0.0.0/14 via y.y.y.y`, but then how I am I meant to get the gateway to do routing after that?

Answer (score -1):

The address x.x.x.x is in the Rackspace service net (a private network shared by all rackspace instances). According to 
Rackspace support, it is not possible to modify their service net routing (in the way that I would like). Their recommendation is to create a Cloud Network (actual private network) and then set gateways and modify routes within that network.